# How add new variable to env?

Tags: go

Some info I don't want hard-code, so `os.Setenv()` is not what I want.

What I've tried:

1. CMD: `go env -w newVar=myVal`
   GOT: go env -w: unknown go command variable newVar
2. Windows, add Environment variables (both System and User), then restart Goland
   GOT: nothing

Any other solution?

---

UPDATE:
IT WORKS: **RESTART COMPUTER** (Windows 10)

Comment: have you tried .env file to store all environment variable https://github.com/joho/godotenv

Comment: @skshahriarahmedraka Thanks. But it's still somewhat hard-code . I don't want store my info in the project.

Comment: `I don't want store my info in the project` - that's why there's `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

people use "tricks" like a .env file or a config.toml or.... any file that holds the values. They make a copy of that like .env_default or config-default.toml. Then in the .gitignore ignore the good ones. And the copies are filled with examples.
So when an other colleague gets everything, there's no real secret in there because that didn't get committed. They can read in the readme what to do with the "default one" and voila...